AWS Cognito update user email attribute
I'm trying to change email for user in cognito but constantly failing. Despite of email attribute is locked as writeable and I could not even change that, it is not updating with default query
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
--user-pool-id YOUR_USER_POOL_ID \
--username USERNAME \
--user-attributes Name=email,Value=NEW_EMAIL

this query returns an error "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminUpdateUserAttributes operation: user.email: Attribute cannot be updated.".
Here is picture of attribute state for my user pool:

Is email even updateable in Cognito or I have to create new user when I need to change email?

Turns out, only user itself might update its email adress.
It should be authorized with scope "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin".
With access token that contain mentioned scope cognito api must be called.
After that user password will be reset and code for password change procedure will be sent to NEW email.
